# DIFFERENCE in Linq

Tags: sql, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Linq have "Difference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041439/does-linq-have-difference)

How to convert the following SQL Query to Linq

```
SELECT * FROM Designation WHERE DIFFERENCE(EmpDesg, ‘Engineer’) >= 3
```

Comment: Documentation: [DIFFERENCE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) - The integer returned is the number of characters in the SOUNDEX values that are the same. The return value ranges from 0 through 4: 0 indicates weak or no similarity, and 4 indicates strong similarity or the same values. (I would have never thought of that one, to be honest)

Comment: Perhaps something like this may help: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/28/entity-sql-user-defined-functions-in-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a stored procedure and bring it into your context, define a user-defined function (if you're using EF) or you need to be willing to just execute a raw SQL query through the context. You can't access `DIFFERENCE` using LINQ to SQL directly (there is no LINQ query opeartor that will be translated into T-SQL `DIFFERENCE`).

Answer (score 1):

[Does Linq have "Difference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041439/does-linq-has-difference/1041805#1041805)

**Summary:**

- Create User-Defined SQL Function
- Add that function to your DBML diagram
- Call that function in your `WHERE` clause